# Fill several times content of same form fields and write it into several lines of a database

Tags: javascript, php, database, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a form. I put a button inside this form called "Add a book". When a user clicks two fields appear : "bookname" and "bookdate" :

```
               <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="add()" href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon-white"></i>Add a book
                </a>
                </div>


                <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- champs du formulaire -->
                <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="add" style="display:none;">
                <!-- Bookname -->   
                <div class="form-row">              
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name of book</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookname" name="bookname">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Bookdate -->   
                <div class="form-row">              
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Date of book</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookdate" name="bookdate">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

When there is only one book, there are no problem to validate the form and write the "bookname" and "bookdate" to the project database. It's very common.
My question is : for example if a user clicks 3 times on the "add book" button and fills 3 times the "bookname" and "bookdate" fields , how could I do in the code to save all that into three different lines in the database ?
That is to say :
*bookname  bookdate

name1     date1

name2     date2

name3     date3*

I don't see how i could do ?
Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you !

Comment: Do you want to reload the page when the form is submitted?

Comment: @Velimir Tchatchevsky : when the form is submitted, it goes to a second page that save and write the fields in the database, then redirects to the first page (the form itself) by reloading this.

Comment: show the js code that adds the extra form inputs, that's where you'll be able to set the different names on the inputs (eg. 'name1', 'name2' etc). PS: @Nick's answer is a more elegant approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the name attribute on your `bookname` and `bookdate` inputs to array notation i.e.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookname" name="bookname[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookdate" name="bookdate[]">
```

Then, in your PHP code, you will find that `$_POST['bookname']` and `$_POST['bookdate']` are now arrays of values, so you can iterate through them e.g.

```
foreach ($_POST['bookname'] as $k => $bookname) {
    $bookdate = $_POST['bookdate'][$k];
    // write bookname and bookdate to database
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed, thank you very very much Nick !